# Request .Form returns null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am not able to retrieve the values in my controller, it is returning null. Please help me find out what I have done wrong.

below is my code

Index.aspx

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/Sample/Index" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <input  type="text" id="PcId" value=<%=Model.PcId %> /></div>
    <input type="file" value="Browse" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save"/></div>
</form>
```

And in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string PcId = Request.Form["PcId"];
    List<string> fileConfigData = new List<string>();

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string FolderPath = mPath.GetFolderPath();
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + PcId) + "\\" + fileName;
        file.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
    return view();
}
```

Comment: You're closing that `<div>` 2 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try adding name to your input field :

```
<input  type="text" id="PcId" name="PcId" value=<%=Model.PcId %>
```

According to The W3C specification, that every form input element should have a name attribute specified. Otherwise that element will not be processed.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls